# Checkbox change innerHTML and call function

Tags: javascript, checkbox, innerhtml

I have a group of `checkboxes`:

```
<form class="form">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified " data-toggle="buttons" name="chartSelect">
                    <label class="btn btn-info" id ="all">
                        <input name="all" type="checkbox" >Hide
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-info">
                        <input name="total" id="total" type="checkbox">Total
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-info">
                        <input name="max" id="max" type="checkbox">Max
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-info">
                        <input name="mean" id="mean" type="checkbox">Mean
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-info">
                        <input name="min" id="min" type="checkbox">Min
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-info">
                        <input name="extrapo" id="extrapolation" type="radio">Extrapo
                    </label>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I'm trying to call two functions depending on whether the button is checked or not and also change the text on the label.

My `JS` attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('[name=all]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        hideAll();
        document.getElementById("all").innerHTML = "Show";
    }
    else {
        showAll();
        document.getElementById("all").innerHTML = "Hide";
    }
});

</script>
```

I can call each function no problem on check and unchecked, but when I change the `innerHTML` the check button stops working.

Comment: document.getElementById is for ID, for name is document.getElementByName ... try document.getElementByName("all") = "Show or Hide"

Comment: ...and inside an event handler, it's just `$(this).html('Show')`

Comment: @CMedina I;m calling `document.getElementByid` on on the label id

Comment: @adeneo I'm not accessing the element called by the event handler, so I can't use `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the value of **innerHTML** and leaving only text there.

**Solution:**
Put the text inside a `span` element

```
<label class="btn btn-info" id="all">
  <input type="checkbox" name="all">
  <span>Hide</span>
</label>
```

**Then in JS do:**

```
 $('input[name="all"]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    hideAll();
    $('#all span').text('Show');
  } else {
    showAll();
    $('#all span').text('Hide');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are selecting the label which selects this HTML element:

```
<label class="btn btn-info" id ="all">
  <input name="all" type="checkbox" >Hide
</label>
```

When you set the innerHTML, you get rid of the input. I'd split up the label and input like this:

```
<input name="all" type="checkbox">
<label class="btn btn-info" id="all">Hide</label>
```